# jQuery call stack?

Tags: json, jquery

I have many instances of the same type of problem using jQuery. Probably because I am missing some basic knowledge (jQuery newb). In my $.Ajax calls to get data - on the success: I perform many calls to other functions based on the data that gets returned. The calls need to be made in a specific order but this does not seem to happen. If I have a call to another jQuery function that I wrote and then three line later have a call to yet another function (which depends on some events that happen in the first function call) the second call is happening first. Ran this with debugger set many times in two different $.Ajax calls and it happens this way. Am I doing something completely wrong?

BTW - the data is coming in just fine and populating my table and form items. Per request I am posting code below - the comments show that GetInventory needs to execute before BuidlNav

```
       $(document).ready(function () {
       $('#searchNow').css('visibility', 'hidden'); //Hide Search Now button
       $("#popup").css("display", "none");
       $('#submit').prop('disabled', true);
       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "mypage.aspx/mywebmethod",
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           data: "{}",
           dataType: "json",
           success: function (states) {
               var jsonCodes = JSON.parse(states.d);
               for (var i in jsonCodes) {
                   $("#Select0").append(new Option(jsonCodes[i].regionname, jsonCodes[i].region_id));
               }
               var first = getUrlVars()["region"];
               if (first) {
                   debugger;
                   $.fn.SetAllSelectors(reg);
                   $.fn.GetInventory(1, 10, reg, 'rank', 'asc'); //This should happen first
                   $.fn.BuildNav(); // This depends on GetInventory having been executed already.                     
               }
               else {
                   var myText = 'United States';
                   $("#Select0 option").filter(function () {
                       return $(this).text() == myText;
                   }).first().prop("selected", true);
                   $.fn.GetChildRegions("Select0");
               }
           }
       });          
   }
);
```

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! It doesn't work like that.

Comment: Can you post some code showing the problem?

Comment: The only thing you're doing wrong is expecting synchronicity out of AJAX. The A is for asynchronous, which means that exactly these things  may happen. In jQuery, you can force synchronous requests, but more likely, your best approach is to re-structure your code with this in mind.

Comment: It looks like you either have some problems with asynchronous nature of $.ajax() call, or your debugger is a bit shaky. Try using console.log (new Date()+' my message '+...) instead to print the timing and whatever info you need. The bottom line is: calls are sequential.

Comment: @ Richard D 0 I will post one of the $.Ajax calls but I am modifying the server function names for security reasons.

Comment: Everyone's using this term *asynchronous* and you might not know what , another term is *out of order*.  You could daisy chain your requests, put the results in an array to be handled later, or tie up your browser and perform a *sync* request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `GetInventory` and `BuildNav` also use ajax, you'll need a structure more like this. When making ajax calls, the data is fetched while not holding up the next command line, so chances are your 2nd or 3rd function is being called before the first finishes.

```
$.ajax({    
   type: "POST",
   url: "mypage.aspx/mywebmethod",
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   data: "{}",
   dataType: "json",
   success: function (states) {
        getInventoryAndBuildNav(states);
   },   
   ... 
});

function getInventoryAndBuildNav(states){
    $.ajax({    
        ....
        url: "mypage.aspx/getinventory",
        success: function (inventory) {

            $.fn.BuildNav();
        },   
        ... 
    });
}
```

The best way to accomplish this is to build functions for each item and allow a callback method to be passed.

Think of it this way

```
$.ajax({    
   type: "POST",
   url: "mypage.aspx/mywebmethod",
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   data: "{}",
   dataType: "json",
   success: function (states) {
       //This will trigger second since we had to wait for the process to finish
        alert('The Ajax call has been made, finished, and the data received');
   }
});

//This will trigger FIRST since the ajax call was initiated, but we're still waiting
alert('The Ajax call has been made. We're moving on to the next call.');
```

Comment: GetInventory does but BuildNav does not. The problem for me with this structure is that GetInventory is large and complex and need to be call from more than one place. Don't want to have to write it many times. There is not a ton of data being returned though so the call does not really need to be async - is there a non async call for data in jQuery?

Comment: Same concept applies - See my updated structure above. You need to make the first ajax call, wait for it to finish, and make the second ajax call, wait for IT to finish, and then call `$.fn.BuildNav();`

Comment: I think the light is starting to trun on slowly. I'll let you know fi this work and thanks much for the input.

Comment: OK so I tried your suggestion and moved the call to BuildNave into the success of the GetInventory function - I now get the following erroor "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'BuildNav"

Comment: Without seeing the entirety of the code, its tough to say why - but essentially it cant find the function - check for syntax errors!

Comment: My bad - I had introduced a new bug when I moved the call. Fixed that bug and now it works so I am marking this as the answer and uv. Thanks

Comment: Glad to hear it. Happy Coding.